# Why functions are written without braces in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the example:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.name} />
```

In this example `name` function does not contain the braces, why? And when I put braces, it will rise the error. I want to know the reason behind this error.

Comment: If you add braces after the function, `this.name()`, you will invoke that function directly on render. You want to give `onChange` a function should be invoked when it is changed, not call it manually yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, a function is an object, much like other objects.

You can assign a function to a variable.

```
let foo = function () {
  return "bar"
}
```

And later you can add the parentheses to that variable name to call the function.

```
foo() // Returns "bar".
```

You can pass the variable around like any other variable, for example as a parameter to another function.

```
function baz (some_function) {
  return some_function()
}

baz(foo) // Returns "bar".
```

This is what happens in your example. `this.name` gets passed to the function that handles the `onChange` event, and at some point inside that function, it adds the parentheses to evaluate the function you passed.

That is why, if you add the parentheses when you pass the function, then the function gets evaluated, and the result is passed:

```
baz(foo()) // Uncaught TypeError: some_function is not a function
```

Here, `foo()` has already been evaluated, and the variable `some_function` in `baz` contains the string `"bar"` instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Function "without braces" is a pointer to some function.

Here is an example.

```
let bananas = function(){ console.log('bananas') }
```

When you do this, you don't call the function, only references it, only create a pointer to the function.
With that reference, you can call `bananas()` any time you want, not only when the code is read.

The reason why you pass only the reference of a function in react is that inside the component, some where, it will call the function.

If you just make this `<input type="text" onChange={this.name()} />`, at the time you are rendering the input, `name()` is called, but if you only pass the reference to the function, react will only call the function when the event (onChange) happen.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are values. It means it can be used on any expression context, like passing values to functions or be returned from functions. A function's value is it own name. Not to be confused with the *return value* of the function.

Parentheses is a JavaScript operator used to create *function call expressions*, between other use cases.

In your case, you are passing the value `this.name` for the property `onChange` of the React's `input` element. The `onChange` expects a `function value` to be called in response to a *change event*. This way, React itself will call the function using the parentheses operator to that end, in this context.

If, otherwise, you've written `this.name()`, you're already making a function call, which will result in a error, since you're bypassing React expected behavior.